# Extract data from String using regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

i' going to extract business value from a String. But my problem is, that the string repeates each time in a loop. And the content syntax is always the same, but the content is changing. 
Thus I need a reg-expr which helps me to extract the data.

What I have tried so far:
`("^\\d{1,2}(.{1})\\s([A-Za-z]{2})\\s(([A-Z]\\d{2,3}))\\s.")`

But the the above provided pattern outputs me only the first three arguments:
**01. Di F929**

Sample String shows like following:

> ```
> 01. Di F929 * Fr F929 Fr FREI Mo S688 Mi S49 * Sa S57 Mo F929 
> Do F224 So S49 Di X337 Fr F56 So FREI \n
> ```

Let me explain how the string is build.

1. (01.) is a digit from 01 to 31.
2. Following be shortWeekDays (German) (Mo, Di, Mi, ..)
3. Word start with Character ends with digit (F929, S49, ...)
4. (Optional) a special character like '*, X, ...'

Important:

```
Di + F929 + *
```

represents single data-block. Each String contains about 12 data-blocks.

My need is, a regular expression which match the above problem. 
Thanks in regard!

Comment: Um...can you tell us what you are trying to match in that sample string?

Comment: Try removing the `^` anchor

Comment: Removing the anchor `^` doesn't help me. The word 'FREI' in the string doesn't appear or doesn't match

Comment: It's really unclear what you want to achieve. Please show some test cases, with input string and expected output.

Comment: Ok, i have solved it.

Comment: Please show the following regex, 
> ^\\d{1,2}(.{1})\\s(([A-Za-z]{2})\\s(([A-Z]\\d{2,3}))\\s.*)*"

Comment: (.{1}) is the same as . so dont overcomplicate that

Comment: Moreover, I guess you want `\.`

Comment: I doubt that, no dots in sample.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/D2lsWG/1

Answer (score 1):

This will help you:

```
(\d{1,2}\.)?\s*([A-Za-z]{2}\s+[A-Z0-9]+\s*[*X]?)\s*
```

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2jpv3o/1/)

Java code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,2}\\.)?\\s*([A-Za-z]{2}\\s+[A-Z0-9]+\\s*[*X]?)\\s*");
        String string = "01. Di F929 * Fr F929 Fr FREI Mo S688 Mi S49 * Sa S57 Mo F929 " +
            "Do F224 So S49 Di X337 Fr F56 So FREI \\n";

        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (m.find())
            System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }
}
```